# How can I create Rectangles in WPF dynamically?

Tags: c#, wpf, rectangles

I am trying to create rectangles and the number of rectangles is depend on data passed from database.
For example, if number = 5, the program will generate 5 rectangles. Also, these rectangles must be able to follow my rectangle property settings, like height, width,color...put them in one line at the end.

Is there a way to do that?

I am using WPF and C#.

Thank you.

Comment: This sounds like homework. We also need to know the language and environment you're working in; the C++ answer will differ from the Java answer which will differ from the C# answer, and all bets are off for Ruby, functional languages, etc.

Comment: "the program"... in what language ? "from database"... what kind ?

Comment: what does it mean to "create rectangles" ?

Answer (score 12):

To create the [rectangle](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.shapes.rectangle.aspx) in code dynamically:

```
int number = 5;
int width = 10;
int height = 10;
int top = 20;
int left = 20;

for (int i = 0; i < number; i++)
{
    // Create the rectangle
    Rectangle rec = new Rectangle()
    {
        Width = width,
        Height = height,
        Fill = Brushes.Green,
        Stroke = Brushes.Red,
        StrokeThickness = 2,
    };

    // Add to a canvas for example
    canvas.Children.Add(rec);
    Canvas.SetTop(rec, top);
    Canvas.SetLeft(rec, left);
}
```